# PHP While Statement Delete only one row from table Mysql PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a while statement and a PDO statement to delete one row if someone clicks the delete button.

```
$companies = $db->query("SELECT * FROM companies LIMIT 50");
while($result = $companies->fetch()) {
                $delete = $db->prepare("DELETE from companies WHERE id=?");
                $response = $delete->execute(array($result['id']));           
   }
}
```

For example:

Company 1 ***DELETE***

Company 2 ***DELETE***

If someone clicks that delete button, I want to delete the company that it is attached to. Right now, when I execute this code and click delete for only one company, it deletes every company in the table.

Comment: Without seeing the query which is generating the `$companies` result set it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Using delete with while loop is quite inefficient, consider using `where id in()` for better performance.

Comment: Put a conditional around the `delete` maybe? How is the record that should be deleted determined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is in the middle of a loop and calls `DELETE` on each record it finds. Not surprisingly, it deletes all companies.

Normally what you do is delete one and only one:

```
$delete = $db->prepare("DELETE from companies WHERE id=?");
$response = $delete->execute(array($_POST['id']));
```

Where `$_POST['id']` represents the posted `id` parameter. The reason POST is used is because some browsers will try and be helpful and pre-fetch any GET links. This means they'll helpfully delete everything.

The convention is to use POST since browsers don't trigger those automatically.

Tools like jQuery make it easy to POST links with `$.post` and such. For example:

```
<a href="/delete" data-id="3" data-method="post" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</a>
```

Where you can then bind automatically to all of these "post" buttons using something like this:

```
$(function() {
  // Augment all postable links with a click handler
  $('a[data-method="post"]').click(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('href'), {
      id: $(this).attr('data-id')
    });

    return false;
  });
});
```

Where using unobtrusive-JavaScript principles you can add this fairly seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

No need while loop just pass single company id and delete via ajax or link or form post method